# Import error on my module, how to fix it?

Tags: python, module

I have made a module called `ArukovicSonicMathility`. I have `pip` installed it

```
pip install ArukovicSonicMathility
```

But when I import it

```py
import ArukovicSonicMathility
```

it gives an error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ArukovicSonicMathility'.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct module name?  Usually module names are lowercase.

Comment: The imported module name is not necessarily the same name that you used for pip.

Comment: i published my module with "camelCase" only.

Comment: @John Gordon ohh, how to fix it?

Comment: If it's your own custom module, then surely you know what the correct module name is?

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and maybe `pip` install modules for one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules. In code you can use `sys.execuateble` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later install module using `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`